# Android: display bullet list in a textview using LeadingMarginSpan?

Tags: java, android, textview, android-xml

I want to display a bullet list in a textview. I can use a bulletspan, but then the bullet isn't very attractive and there doesn't seem to be a way of customizing it. I want to use the default bullet (•) for my bulletpoint list. Is there a way of using LeadingMarginSpan to get the effect that I want? Basically, if the line begins with a bullet I want it aligned to the left, but if the line is so long that it breaks then the text on the next line down (broken text) should be indented to the same level as the text after the bulletpoint.

```
* for example
instead of this

* for example
  should look like this
```

my current code:

```
String[] bulletpoint = {some array of strings};
CharSequence allText = "";

for (int i = 0; i < bulletpoint.length; i++) {
    String text = bulletpoint[i];
    SpannableString s = new SpannableString(text + "\n");
    s.setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan(BulletSpan.STANDARD_GAP_WIDTH) {
        @Override
        public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
            return 0;
        }
        @Override
        public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {

        }
    }, 0, text.length(), 0);
    allText = TextUtils.concat(allText, s);
}
textview.settext(allText);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer with code example:

```
CharSequence allText = "";
for (String aBulletpoint : bulletpoint) {
    String text = aBulletpoint.trim() + ".";
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(text + "\n");
    spannableString.setSpan(new LeadingMarginSpan() {
        @Override
        public int getLeadingMargin(boolean first) {
            return getString(R.string.bulletpoint).length() * 50;
        }
        @Override
        public void drawLeadingMargin(Canvas c, Paint p, int x, int dir, int top, int baseline, int bottom, CharSequence text, int start, int end, boolean first, Layout layout) {
            if (first) {
                Paint.Style orgStyle = p.getStyle();
                p.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
                c.drawText(getString(R.string.bulletpoint) + " ", 0, bottom - p.descent(), p);
                p.setStyle(orgStyle);
            }
         }
    }, 0, text.length(), 0);
    allText = TextUtils.concat(allText, spannableString);
}
someTextView.setText(allText);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use either `BulletSpan` or the `LeadingMarginSpan` implementation, just override `drawLeadingMargin()` to draw the bullet the exact way you want.

Refer to the code for `BulletSpan` to see how they draw the bullet and use that as a guide:

[BulletSpan source code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/java/android/text/style/BulletSpan.java)